# How to separate a list of strings into several lines within a row/cell?

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

i have a string ['A', 'B', 'C'] in a cell of a dataframe which is imported from a CSV file by Python Pandas (looks exactly the same as the (row 1, ColA) below).

Now i wanna make it like (row 2, ColA) in the panda dataframe, as the uploaded pic below, how do i achieve it? I also want it to look like this in the excel when i save it to CSV by using to_CSV.

[image]

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA' : "['A','B','C']"}, index=[1])
```

Output:

```
         ColA
1   ['A','B','C']
2         A
          B
          C
```

I believe text.explode isn't a solution as it separates the list into several rows.
Thank you! and Wish you guys a healthy and safe new year!

Comment: This is very confusing. Is the original list retained? Are the list items exploded into their own rows or is there just a difference in what is printed? Are you working with lists or strings? Images tell us none of these things.

Comment: thank you for dropping by, i have edited my question. Hope it is clearer this time.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. For future reference it would also be very helpful to add some sample data or code to generate the sample, along with the expected output (as an output DataFrame). That makes it easier to put together a working answer that we can be confident works for your use case.

Comment: @yts61 I have updated your question so that input/output are text. Please no images in the future and if I am incorrect on input / output, then please edit correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some cleanup with `replace`. With `replace` I have two different patterns within the string, for which I want two separate replacements. One replacements is `'\n'`, so I can see on new lines when sending to excel. The other replacement is replacing with an empty string, i.e. *nothing*. The `or` operator `|` separates the different possible replacements for the empty string output of `''`. `[` and `]` are `regex` characters, so you must escape with `\`, so you are basically getting rid of `[`, `]` and `'`. You must also pass `regex=True` to `replace`.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA' : "['A','B','C']"}, index=[1])
df['ColA'] = df['ColA'].replace(["','", "\[|\]|'"], ['\n', ''], regex=True)
df
Out[1]: 
      ColA
1  A\nB\nC
```

And output in Excel after expanding row width:

[image]

Comment: thank you David, but i want all A, B, C in the same row/cell, is there any other way?

Comment: @yts61 EDIT: `df['ColA'] = df['ColA'].replace(["','", "\[|\]|'"], ['\n', ''], regex=True)` is simpler.